# Assert.AreEqual On Fail Throws Exception

Tags: c#, nunit

I am new to the Unit Testing And using Nunit i dont know how to pass this exception but there is an AssertionUnhandled Exception.

I am doing

```
Assert.AreEqual(exists, 1 == (int)ExecScalar(string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*)    
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{0}{1}' AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='{2}'", 
            (audit ? DBHelper.AuditTablePrefix : ""), tableName, schema)));
```

Here exists = true and in my case other comes to 1==0 so it says Expected True but false.

So what should i do because i dont know how can i move further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to test? What is valid exit condition for the test?

Comment: Get in the habit of using parameterized queries everywhere. Prevent SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to ensure that particular query returns `1` as tables count,
I would suggest you to wrap such complex query in `Assert.DoesNotThrow()` and use `Assert.AreEqual()` to compare two values:

```
int numberOfTables = -1;

Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => numberOfTablesRaw = 
             (int)ExecScalar(string.Format(
             "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{0}{1}' AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='{2}'",  
             (audit ? DBHelper.AuditTablePrefix : ""), 
              tableName, 
              schema)));

Assert.AreEqual(1, numberOfTables);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it needs to throw exception (expected situation), you can use this code:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(delegate { throw new ArgumentException() } );
```

or add

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
```

near your [Test] declaration.

Comment: I'd use `Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => classUnderTest.SomeMethod());` I don't miss the old delegate syntax.